# redmine sso openId connect plugin

Tags: plugins, single-sign-on, keycloak, openid, redmine

In our company we are using various apps we need to integrate apps with keycloak using sso. For redmine we have redmine openid connect plugin there we have list of feilds

1. openId connect server url:
   **https://our-company-keycloak/auth/realms/test-realm**  (We provided this link)
2. OpenID Connect scopes (comma-separated): openId scopes we provided
   **email,username**
3. client ID : **redmine **(From keycloak )
4. client secret : ***** ( From keycloak redmine client secret
   provided)
5. Disable Ssl Validation : checkmark **enabled**
6. Create user if not exists : checkmark **enabled**

Can you tell me still any changes needed or not.
I have tried by filling all the above details.

- Am getting error after clicking on **login with sso** it is taking us
  to company and in error occurs in keycloak stating **Invalid
  Parameter Redirect uri**
- In that uri it is displaying redirect uri as **local host 3000** but and
  not using that port can u help me how to fix this